# Login to a webpage from java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I want to make a java program to auto login at http://www.eclass.teikal.gr/eclass2/

When I run this I take as result the same page! Where am I doing wrong ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

    http.sendPost();

}



// HTTP POST request
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

//      String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
    String url = "http://www.eclass.teikal.gr/eclass2/index.php";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    URL obj1 = new URL ("http://www.eclass.teikal.gr/eclass2/");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) obj1.openConnection();


    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "uname=my_username&pass=my_password&submit=";


    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

}
```

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you run this request from some tool, where you can submit http post request, what does happen? What does server return? This behavior may be intentional, that url is same but content may be different.

Comment: @Leos Normaly it returns the same url but with different content as you wrote, but with this code the return is tha same url with the same content (the page with the login form).

Comment: Try to submit this request from some other tool, for example firefox plugin HTTP Resource test. Then you will find if the problem is in your request or in your code.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I tried that you suggest me and the problem is in my request. I think that maybe there is this problem because there are two forms in the page but I read the code and the "login" form hasn't got any name/id.  Thank's for your help!

Comment: Glad to read. I copied the correct comment as answear so you can accept it.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Could you maybe have a look and give any advice for the request?

Comment: I though that it is working already, that you found the issue. The source code looks OK, I did not find issue (except unused conn1 that is not closed at the end). Make work your request in some tool first.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I'm working my request with firefox plugin HTTP Resource test but I can't find something. If you could help me I'll be pleasure.  Thank's!

Comment: @LeosLiterak I have tried to submit this request with Postman tool for chrome and worked. Have you got something in your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to submit this request from some other tool, for example firefox plugin HTTP Resource test. Then you will find if the problem is in your request or in your code.

Comment: I have check it again and again! Finaly I found that the problem is with the code. I tried a few tools to submit the request and the problem is with cookies. Every tool which work with cookies run ok, but with other tools the response content write that this connection is not possible because I have disabled cookies in my browser. Any Idea?

Comment: Could you rephrase? If you submit the request in postman, does returned data contain logged user?

Comment: I can see one potential problem here - redirect after post is common pattern. So the first response might return new location and cookie. If you open the redirected location and do not pass the cookie, you are forgotten.

Comment: I think that you are right! I don't know how to correct my code to pass the cookie.

Comment: How does response look? What is there? You shall see it in Postman